# c# HTML inline style quote problems

Tags: c#, html, css, escaping

I am using c# to write an HTML Table in an email that will be sent to a few support staff within our organization.

I want to add an alternating background colour to the TR elements.

I have tried this:

```
sb.Append("<tr style=&quot;"background-color:#E0E0E0;"&quot;>");
```

or this:

```
sb.Append("<tr style=background-color:#ffffff;>");
```

but judging from the squiggly red line underneath the first one I have got it wrong.

How should I code this so the quotes are escaped and the style is added inlibne within the HTML table

Comment: You need to understand what escape characters mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine escaping the quotes would work:

```
sb.Append("<tr style=\"background-color:#ffffff;\">");
```

Comment: You could also use single quotes: `sb.Append("<tr style='background-color:#ffffff;'>");`

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to do this is to escape the quotes.

```
sb.Append("<tr style=\"background-color:#E0E0E0;\">");
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just escape the quotes using

```
sb.Append("<tr style=\"background-color:#E0E0E0;\">");
```